# I'm having trouble figuring out what this time stamp means

Tags: python, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have been trying to figure out what kind of timestamp takes this form:

*2012-07-02T21:27:41.229431*

It seems like it is some sort of unix time, but I can't figure out what the 6 digits after the decimal point represent.

I'm assuming 21 is the hour, 27 is the minute, and 41 is the second. Obviously next would be milliseconds, but it seems like 6 digits would be too high precision. Could someone please help?

By the way, this was produced in Python, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digits after the decimal point are fractions of a second.

The six digits represent microseconds, which are 10^-6 of a second and so require 6 digits to represent.

See the table here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix for a complete list of the metric prefixes and their corresponding number of digits after the decimal point.

The precision of a timestamp depends on the precision of the clock used to measure it. Because period is the inverse of frequency, a clock with a 1 kHz frequency is capable of counting miliseconds, while a 1 MHz clock is required for microseconds. Nanoseconds require a 1 GHz clock, etc.

Comment: You were first! -- I need to wait 7 minutes... your time will come.

Comment: OK :), meantime I will improve the answer by relating to clock speed in response to your query regarding possible precision

Comment: The six digits only represent microseconds because there happen to be six of them.  There could just as easily be one digit or 10.  It's just an ordinary decimal fraction.  It's not anything peculiar to the ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 1):

The seconds are just an ordinary decimal number, so "41.229431" means 41.229431 seconds after the start of the minute.  Since there are six digits after the decimal, that means that the precision of the timestamp extends to microseconds in this case, but there could just as easily be fewer or many more digits.

Comment: I guess I didn't realize that timestamps were ever this precise.

Comment: Considering that most modern computer CPU's have clock speeds measured in gigaherz (1 GHz = one billion per second), they can measure microseconds pretty reliably.

Answer (score 0):

ISO-8601

The 6 digits after the decimal are microseconds.